# Blender: rotating an entire animation

Tags: animation, rotation, blender

I have an object that, over a number of frames, is translated on the Y-axis.

Is it possible to change the animated translation so that the object moves across the X-axis instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple movement along one axis you will probably find it easier to just delete existing keyframes and create new ones.

For more complex movements you can copy and paste keyframes within the graph editor or the dopesheet.

In your example you need to have a keyframe on the x location so that the x location is visible within the graph editor. You then select the y location keyframes and copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). Then select the x location in the list to the side and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>). The first keyframe in the selection that was copied will be placed on the x location at the current frame with others offset relative to it. Any existing keyframes on the target channel will still exist unless an added keyframe falls on the same frame to overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, that was it! Copying the frames from "Y Delta Location" to "X Delta Location" worked perfectly, thank you.